# ThemeOverlay.AppCompat & android:colorBackground property

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-styles, android-toolbar

Im trying to override background color of my Toolbar and I can not understand why by overriding `android:background` property it works, instead overriding `android:colorBackground` it doesnt work. 
I looked at Appcompat's theme (V 22.2.0) and I saw that there is `android:colorBackground` property, and there isnt `android:background`.
Can someone explain that?

**Edit** 
Second related question: I saw that *Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat* has no parent. So, from where *ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar* inherits its `android:background` property?

***layout***

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
android:id="@+id/toolBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle" />
```

***style***

```
<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#2578bc</item>
    <!-- <item name="android:colorBackground">#2578bc</item> THIS DOESNT WORK -->
</style>
```

***AppCompat's theme_base.xml***

```
<style name="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/bright_foreground_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorForegroundInverse">@color/bright_foreground_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@color/abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_dark</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/abc_primary_text_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryDisableOnly">@color/abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/abc_secondary_text_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiaryInverse">@color/abc_secondary_text_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/hint_foreground_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHintInverse">@color/hint_foreground_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/highlighted_text_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/link_text_material_dark</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">?android:attr/textColorSecondary</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/ripple_material_dark</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/button_material_dark</item>
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/switch_thumb_material_dark</item>

    <!-- Used by MediaRouter -->
    <item name="isLightTheme">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: if you want to change the background of toolbar ..use
<item name="colorPrimary">Your toolbar color</item>

Comment: I know it, my question is why colorBackground doesnt work.